# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty kA^k$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, matrix-norms

Let $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ be any matrix norm and let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix with $\lVert A\rVert < 1$. I'd like to show that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty kA^k$ converges, but I don't understand how to make use of the fact $\lVert A\rVert < 1$. Using the definition of a matrix norm, I get the following (useless) result. $$\left\lVert\sum_{k=0}^n kA^k\right\rVert \leq \sum_{k=0}^n k\left\lVert A\right\rVert^k = \frac{n\left\lVert A\right\rVert^{n+2} -\left(n+1\right)\left\lVert A\right\rVert^{n+1}+ \left\lVert A\right\rVert}{\left(1-\left\lVert A\right\rVert\right)^2}$$
I also looked into Cauchy's convergence test, but I had no success applying it. How can I prove convergence?

Comment: What happens if $A=I_n$ is the identity matrix and $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm (so that $\|A\|=1$, in particular)?

Comment: @SangchulLee I am sorry, $\lVert A\rVert < 1$ is given. (not $\lVert A\rVert \leq 1$)

Comment: Apply Ratio test to $\sum kc^{k}$ where $c=\|A\|\in [0,1)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm This would only show that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty kc^k$ converges, which is not the same as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty kA^k$.

Comment: If you can bound the second expression, your Matrix series will converge. Don't let $A$ distract you. $\lVert A \rVert$ is a number. Set for example $c := \lVert A \rVert$, then you'll see it very clearly. Just apply ration test then.

Comment: @Meowdog How does finding an upper bound of $\left\lVert\sum_{k=0}^n kA^k\right\rVert$ show convergence? $\left\lVert\sum_{k=0}^n kA^k\right\rVert\leq 0$ would show that $\sum_{k=0}^n kA^k$ converges towards 0, but every other upper bound would not immideately show convergence.

Comment: You can prove the following: If $(X_k)$ is a sequence of $n\times n$ matrices and if $\sum_k \|X_k\|<\infty$, then $\sum_k X_k$ also converges. (*Hint:* Invoke the Cauchy criterion for the convergence of a series!) Then you can adopt geetha290krm's comment.

Comment: It does, as @Sangchul Lee said, because of the Cauchy criterion. Central to this is that the space of $n \times n$-matrices is complete

Comment: @SangchulLee The convergence theorem you stated sounds really useful, but I am struggling to prove it (even with your hint). Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be the space of all $n\times n$ matrices with real entries, endowed with a matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$. We prove:

> **Theorem.** Suppose $(X_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of matrices such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \|X_k\| < \infty$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} X_k$ converges.

*Proof.* Let $S_k = \sum_{j=1}^{k} X_j$ be the partial sums. We need to prove that $(S_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converges in $V$. Since $V$ is complete (in the sense that every Cauchy sequence converges in $V$), it suffices to show that $(S_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence. To make use of the assumption $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \|X_k\| < \infty$, we also introduce the partial sums $T_k = \sum_{j=1}^{k} \|X_j\|$. Then, for any $k < l$, we have

$$ \| S_l - S_k \|
= \left\| \sum_{j=k+1}^{l} X_j \right\|
\leq \sum_{j=k+1}^{l} \|X_j\|
= T_l - T_k. $$

Since $T_l - T_k \to 0$ as $l, k \to \infty$, it follows that $(S_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is indeed Cauchy and hence convergent. $\square$

Using this theorem, it is now straightforward to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k A^k$ converges for $A$ with $\|A\| < 1$.

---

*Addendum.* In fact, the property of "absolutely convergent series being convergent series" is the characterizing property of Banach space:

> **Theorem.** Let $V$ be a normed vector space endowed with a norm $\|\cdot\|$. Then the followings are equivalent:
>
> 1. $V$ is a Banach space, i.e., it is a complete normed space.
> 2. In $V$, every "absolutely convergent" series converges. More precisely, for any sequence $(x_k)$ in $V$ the following implication holds:
>    $$ \text{if} \quad \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \|x_k\| < \infty, \qquad \text{then} \quad \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k \quad \text{converges.} $$

See the [related article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Definition), for instance.